# How to return literals of Datatype xsd:string with french language in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf

i'm still learning SPARQL syntax, but I am stuck in this query. This is what I have reached so far.

```
PREFIX : <https://ar.wikipedia.org/>

SELECT ?label
FROM <https://ar.wikipedia.org/>
WHERE {
    ?s ?p ?label .
    FILTER( lang(?label) = "fr" )
    
}
```

Any idea where did I go wrong?

Comment: it would be helpful to mention where exactly you're running the query and what "does not work" mean. I'd also restrict the query to `rdfs:label` properties only if your interested in French labels only. Nevertheless, does this graph `https://ar.wikipedia.org/` exist in your triple store? Also, don't mix up Dbpedia and Wikipedia please

Comment: You might wanyt to use `langMatches` as well: `FILTER langMatches( lang(?title), "FR" )` which is not case sensitive and deals with "fr-ca" etc.